# How to hide td in a table (efficiently) starting from the second td (included)?

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say I have a table like the one below:

```
   <table id='randData'>
    <tr>
       <td >56</td>
       <td >Call me</td>
       <td >Blah</td>
       ...
    </tr>
   <tr>
  </table>
```

What is the best way to hide the tds starting from the second (included) till the end?
Adding a class for the tds that will be hidden is more efficient? Is there a way of solving
this using an expression with nth-child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery `.not()` and `:first` selector.

```
$('table tr td:not(:first)').hide();
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/3dzxsxgq/

Answer (score 3):

I'll present 2 simple ways!

## #1

**The idea: Hide *every* `td` tag, and then un-hide the 1st one.**

```
tr > td {
    display: none; /* Hidden! */
}
tr > td:first-child {
    display: initial; /* Undo hiding on only the 1st td */
}
```

## #2

**The idea: Hide every sibling beyond the 1st child**

```
tr > td ~ td {
    display: none;
}
```

The reason I'm giving the 1st option as well as this one is that not everyone likes the `~` selector (which selects all children beyond the child to the left of the `~` symbol in case you're not familiar with it!)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are animating with jQuery I prefer to just use classes which I think everyone will agree is the most efficient way. You can select all the `td` elements from the second and up like this in CSS:

```
tr.hide > td:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none;
}
```

Now just drop the `hide` class on the rows you want to hide the 2nd and up.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#randData td").eq(1).nextUntil("tr").hide();`

would be my immediate guess if you MUST use jQuery